# Qt stylesheet for all QProgressBars programmatically (C++)

Tags: c++, css, qt, qstylesheet

Having trouble understanding how to **programmatically set a stylesheet to be applied on several (or even all) widgets** in Qt Creator 4.1 (Qt 5.7) with C++.

For example, say I have 3 progress bar widgets; I have explicitly set each with the same stylesheet with **css** like so:

```
ui->c1->setStyleSheet("QProgressBar {"
                          "background-color: #74c8ff;"
                          "color: #0a9dff;"
                          "border-style: outset;"
                          "border-width: 2px;"
                          "border-color: #74c8ff;"
                          "border-radius: 7px;"
                          "text-align: left; }"

                          "QProgressBar::chunk {"
                          "background-color: #010327; }");

ui->c2->setStyleSheet("QProgressBar {"
                          "background-color: #74c8ff;"
                          "color: #0a9dff;"
                          "border-style: outset;"
                          "border-width: 2px;"
                          "border-color: #74c8ff;"
                          "border-radius: 7px;"
                          "text-align: left; }"

                          "QProgressBar::chunk {"
                          "background-color: #010327; }");

ui->c3->setStyleSheet("QProgressBar {"
                          "background-color: #74c8ff;"
                          "color: #0a9dff;"
                          "border-style: outset;"
                          "border-width: 2px;"
                          "border-color: #74c8ff;"
                          "border-radius: 7px;"
                          "text-align: left; }"

                          "QProgressBar::chunk {"
                          "background-color: #010327; }");
```

I would like to use the [Qt Stylesheets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet.html) to create a stylesheet for my widgets and avoid all this code suplication.

After reading the docs, the syntax would be like this :

```
QProgressBar
{
    background: #74c8ff;
    color: #0a9dff;
    border-style: outset;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #74c8ff;
    border-radius: 7px;
    text-align: left;
}
QProgressBar::chunk
{
    background-color: #010327;
}
```

but, apparently you cannot copy the parameter names as used in a `setStylesheet` with css directly to a syntax like the one above.

I also tried something like this

```
QProgressBar.setStyleSheet("QProgressBar {"
                           "background-color: #74c8ff;"
                           "color: #0a9dff;"
                           "border-style: outset;"
                           "border-width: 2px;"
                           "border-color: #74c8ff;"
                           "border-radius: 7px;"
                           "text-align: left; }"

                           "QProgressBar::chunk {"
                           "background-color: #010327; }");
```

None of the above worked (undeclared identifiers and syntax errors).

Could someone provide an example of how you can achieve defining a single stylesheet with the above parameters to be applied for all widgets? If you could point to a resource (I could not find anything!) that explains the available parameters to achive my goal, that would be as good).

Finally, if such a stylesheet is created for all progress bars, **how can I exclude one progress bar** (or any widget for that matter) from having that stylesheet and have instead a different one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `qApp->setStyleSheet` instead of `QProgressBar.setStyleSheet` to set stylesheet for all widgets in your application. More examples here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html

Comment: That works, thanks. Regarding how to exclude a widget from having that stylesheet, is there anything I can do besides giving that widget a new stylesheet just for it? Also, can I have 2 stylesheets so that some of the progress bars follow one and the other progress follow the second?

Comment: @nk-fford you can set specific stylesheet for the specific widget using `WidgetType#widgetName` syntax in stylesheet string. But I couldn't figure out how to use default stylesheet for the specified widget, an empty string does not work for me